# How to compile ClickHouse in CLion?

Tags: cmake, compilation, clion, clickhouse, ninja

I'm trying to build ClickHouse in CLion.

I follow the [official documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/development/developer-instruction/#ide-integrated-development-environment). I was able to build ClickHouse from the command line, however, I would also like to be able to build it in CLion.

The documentation doesn't give out much information on how to do that, only implies that it's possible. ClickHouse's [GitHub Issues search by 'CLion'](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues?q=clion) also do not offer much advice.

ClickHouse uses CMake and Ninja. The documentation mentions that one can use either Ninja or make instead of Ninja to compile in CLion.

I tried both and got many errors. For example, when running with CMake settings set to `-G Ninja`, I was able to build the target `common` but I get the following error when building the target `clickhouse-client`:

```
====================[ Build | clickhouse-client | Debug ]=======================
/usr/bin/cmake --build /tmp/tmp.CAA3nJhi8z/cmake-build-debug --target clickhouse-client
[1/7338] Generating lber-version.c
FAILED: contrib/openldap-cmake/lber-version.c 
cd /tmp/tmp.CAA3nJhi8z/contrib/openldap && /usr/bin/cmake -E env bash -c "/tmp/tmp.CAA3nJhi8z/contrib/openldap/build/mkversion -v '2.5.X' liblber.la > \"/tmp/tmp.CAA3nJhi8z/cmake-build-debug/contrib/openldap-cmake/lber-version.c\""
bash: /tmp/tmp.CAA3nJhi8z/contrib/openldap/build/mkversion: Permission denied
[18/7338] Building CXX object contrib/..._/icu/icu4c/source/i18n/calendar.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I also use a remote toolchain in CLion to build on a server, not my laptop. Since it's a permission issue, I assume I have to run the build from sudo but I'm not sure how to do that, and searching only offers a guide on [How to debug as root in CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/debug-as-root.html).

Question #2. Is it OK that after CMake loaded in CLion, I don't see any green arrows in the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) in the root of the ClickHouse project? I can only see targets in the top right corner dropdown ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mWs3.png)).

Question #3. I'm also unsure how to build all the binaries in CLion. E.g. in the command line, I would just run `ninja` but in CLion there are so many targets, and none of them is named like `build all`.

Any pointers to a solution are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a remote build, the Clion first copies all source files to the remote machine. And if the option

`Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Deployment -> Options -> Preserve original file permissions`

is not enabled, it does not save the executable permissions to run some scripts. Which breaks the build.

Therefore, you can either enable this option and re-upload the files or set permission `x` manually to the files that will be logged in the error message.